# How to display more then one fetch function in one page using loops ( in php )?

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops

I'm trying to display the countries of each continent , so in one page i set some buttons (one for each continent ) , and what i want is : when the user click in a button the countries of the continent (that the user choose ) will display . But , the problem is : i can only click the button and display the countries only of the first request that i wrote in my code , and when i click a second time in another button (another continent) the countries didn't display . and i get those errors :

> the variable "africa" is undefined .

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function fetch() on null ..

Here are the two first requests & the two first loops :

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['africa']) ) {

    $africa=$baseblog->prepare('select country from countries where continent="Africa" ');
    $africaaa=$africa->execute(array());
    var_dump($africaaa);
    echo "  <br> ";

} elseif (isset($_POST['asia']) ) {

    $asia=$baseblog->prepare('select country from countries where continent="Asia" ');
    $asiaaa=$asia->execute(array());
    // var_dump($asiaaa);
    // echo "  <br> ";

}
?>

<!-- affichage des pays africa -->
<div class="divpays">
    <ul>
        <?php while ($africa1=$africa->fetch()) { ?>
        <li  style="text-align: center"> <?php echo $africa1['country'] ?> </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<!-- affichage des pays asia -->
<div class="divpays">
    <ul>
        <?php  while ($asia1=$asia->fetch()) { ?>
        <li  style="text-align: center"> <?php echo $asia1['country'] ?> </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: The variable cannot exists when the `if` is not run.

Comment: I would use a `select` in the HTML and let the user select the continent. Then you can just use the value in the `select`. `select country from countries where continent=?` and `...->execute(array($_POST['continent']))`

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: the concept of what i'm trying to do , we apply it in react , i don't know if it will work here

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some encapsulation by a class or at the very least, a function, to make this clearer and cleaner. As noted in comments, you are using a condition based on the post so either AFRICA or ASIA (or neither when someone first arrives at this page) is the choice, so you can not show both iterations below whilst only allowing for one choice at the top UNLESS you have have a default value set or you hide the one not being called in the POST.

I would create an encapsulated version of your business logic first *(this is kind of a model and controller in one here, but if you aren't even using any encapsulation at all, then at this point, that concept doesn't really matter)*:

**/vendor/MyClass/Model.php**

```
<?php
namespace MyClass;

class Model
{
    private $request, $con;
    /**
     *  @note  Make sure to pass in the $_POST and your database connection.
     *         They don't have to be typed, but it helps keep things working
     *         and if you have a good IDE, it makes programming easier
     */
    public function __construct(array $request, \PDO $con)
    {
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->con = $con;
    }
    /**
     *  @note  Here you would try and fetch by the POST country.
     *         It would be better if the key was called "country" and the
     *         value would be "asia" or "africa" etc. It makes this
     *         part easier/cleaner 
     */
    public function getFromRequest(string $def = null)
    {
        # Determine what country to fetch
        if(isset($this->request['asia']))
            $country = 'asia';
        elseif(isset($this->request['africa']))
            $country = 'africa';
        # Stop and return nothing OR you are able to return a default
        if(empty($country))
            return (!empty($def))? $this->get($def) : false;
        # Return a successful selection
        return $this->get($country);
    }
    /**
     *  @note  This is just a general query engine that can be reused
     */
    public function get(string $country)
    {
        # Use the injected db connection to query
        $query = $this->con->prepare('SELECT `country` FROM `countries` WHERE `continent` = ?');
        # Execute. Presuming all your values use title case, you can
        # manipulate the string here to make sure whatever is passed
        # in will be correct
        $fetch = $query->execute([ ucwords(strtolower($country)) ]);
        # Create the loop
        while($result = $fetch->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $row[] = $result;
        }
        # Return the result
        return (!empty($row))? $row : false;
    }
}
```

**/thisfile.php**

```
<?php
# Include the model
include_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/MyClass/Model.php');
# Create the instance, make sure to pass the post and your db connection
$MyClass = new \MyClass\Model($_POST, $baseblog);
# Fetch the country array, using "africa" as the default for when a
# $_POST is not set
$selCountry = $MyClass->getFromRequest('africa');
# Even though we are sure there will be returned an array of data, it's best
# to check that it's available first, just in case. This should still be
# error/warning-free if you removed "africa" as the default value.
if($selCountry): ?>
    <div class="divpays">
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($selCountry as $cou): extract($cou); ?>
            <li style="text-align: center">
                <?php echo $country ?>
            </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

> I should note, I haven't tested this, but it should be enough to get the proof-of-concept.

---

**EDIT:**

After re-reading your post, you may ALSO be trying to fetch multiple countries on the same page and activating them one at a time via a button, with the hope that you can keep previous clicked ones selected. This code, in its current state, is not going to do that. You would need to create this as an ajax-based solution, though you can keep the Model as is in this scenario:

**/ajax/country_select.php**

```
<?php
include_once(realpath(__DIR__.'../').'/vendor/MyClass/Model.php');
$MyClass = new \MyClass\Model($_POST, $baseblog);
# Fetch the country array if set, no default
$selCountry = $MyClass->getFromRequest();
# Stop if no country
if(!$selCountry)
    return false ?>

<div class="divpays">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($selCountry as $cou): extract($cou); ?>
        <li style="text-align: center">
            <?php echo $country ?>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am going to use jquery here...

**/thisfile.php**

```
<h3>Click a country to get started!</h3>
<button class="country-selector">Africa</button>
<button class="country-selector">Asia</button>
<div id="country-drop"></div>


<script>
    $(function(){
        // Listen for button click
        $('.country-selector').on('click', function(e) {
            // Stop the button from doing whatever it would normally do
            e.preventDefault();
            // This is the default data
            var dataSet = {
                url: '/ajax/country_select.php',
                dataType: 'html',
                method: 'post',
                success: r => {
                    // We want to append into the country container
                    $('#country-drop').append(r);
                }
            };
            // Fetch the value from the button
            let sel = $(this).text();
            // Remove the button because we don't want people to use it again
            $(this).replaceWith('');
            // Create our post key, again, this would be much better if
            // the key was named "country" and the value was the country
            // name
            dataSet[sel] = true;
            // Do the ajax
            $.ajax(dataSet);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i think the logic that i'm trying to apply here in php is unacceptable . react it's a single page , we can display so many components in one page . and i tried to do the same logic in php . I think is not correct to do it in php